# Sphinx and JavaScript Documentation Workflow

Tags: javascript, python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

For my JavaScript framework I would like to use Sphinx. Since I am new in the Sphinx world I would like you people to help me out getting started with Sphinx and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for Sphinx' [JavaScript Domain](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/domains.html#the-javascript-domain) feature.

**Edit:** From a quick glean at the documentation & tools, it doesn't look like you can use ReST inside your JavaScript. You'll either have to fish out the documentation from the comments, or keep it around in sidecar-files.

Comment: Thats fine, I dont want to use ReST inside my JavaScript library, it would be good if all the library members are automatically detected along with associated comments by the sphinx.

Comment: I don't quite follow; »auto-detect library« members and »associated comments by sphinx«? AFAIK, Sphinx doesn't know how to read JavaScript-code at all, so it can neither parse out functions or their associated documentation for you. That's why I suggested the use of sidecar files.

Comment: This is a delayed response on this, but I had been looking to see if someone else had done this. When I couldn't find anything, I just built something.
https://github.com/Nuulogic/sphinx-jsapidoc
I'd qualify it as alpha and it's _very_, _very_ specific about the syntax you use -- It wants pure javascript.
I have only tested it on the internal code for the company I work for, but it's working pretty solid for us.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for too late response )

Like you I want build docs for my own JS framework based on AngularJS.

And like oliverseal, I am built sphinx extension in native way for sphinx and ext.autodoc
[sphinxcontrib-autoanysrc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinxcontrib-autoanysrc)

It simple and clean, but does have ext.autodoc features for auto generation signatures and others, but it enough for me store reST docs of framework API in js files )

You can implement ext.autodoc features with sphinxcontrib-autoanysrc extension check out  [autoanysrc.JSAnalyzer](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx-contrib/src/tip/autoanysrc/sphinxcontrib/analyzers/javascript.py?at=default)