# Sphinx API documentation for Javascript

Tags: javascript, python-sphinx

I am using Sphinx extensively for documentation and feel comfortable with it.

However, more more I found myself doing Javascript (front-end) than Python.

Are there any plug-ins or ways to do similar API documentation from JavaScript code comments with Sphinx as there is with Python docstrings?

Comment: You might be interested in this thread on the sphinx mailinglist: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/sphinx-dev/D8_utlZQTaE

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8644751/407651.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, so I wrote [sphinx-js](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinx-js/) to address it. It's basically autodoc for JavaScript, with a few other niceties. There's a [more in-depth writeup](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/07/introducing-sphinx-js-a-better-way-to-document-large-javascript-projects/) over at the Mozilla Hacks blog. Advantages over similar packages are better polish, no Java dependency, standard JSDoc syntax in your source, and an autodoc-esque rather than an include-based workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [jsdoc-for-sphinx](https://github.com/stdbrouw/jsdoc-for-sphinx). I haven't tried it so no idea how well that works.